# how to get multiple values from selected single item in angular 8

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7, dropdown, asp.net-core-webapi

i'm Populating dropdown with multiple Values like **productId,productName,skuId,Sku,Category Id**. and displaying with dropdown displaying with **productName.**

Data binding from Webapi to dropdown.

In ts File

this.productData = response.result;

```
<select id="prodcode" class="form-control" formControlName="prodCode"   required>
           <option [value]="''">Product Code</option>
           <option [value]="product.productId"
             *ngFor="let product of productData">                                    
              {{product.productName}}</option>
 </select>
```

hear i Can get productId only with formcontrol. i need to get in ts file all reaming datails like

**productName,skuId,Sku,Category Id.**

so kindily looking solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have an product object by binding a value with `[ngValue]`.

```html
<option [ngValue]="product" *ngFor="let product of productData">
  {{product.productName}}
</option>
```

Comment: @user3257223 in TS file, you can get data by `prodCode` that you named in `formControlName`

Comment: zmag how to bind  dropdown productid in edit mode ? im  written like .....  this.productForm.reset({
            prodCode: row.ProductId )};..hear not able to get that product..